# How to disable access to the part of my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is some Rails app with 2 parts: admin panel and API for the mobile client. My Rails app uses HTTPS, and I want to disable access to the API through browser, only through my       mobile client. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Just an Idea, and I am not sure if it can work, but maybe, a mobile-client gives a different [Browser ID](http://kluge.in-chemnitz.de/tools/browser.php). Maybe you could check, if it's a mobile-client-ID, or any other ID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [User-Agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#user-agent) is a way to tell where the requests come from.

When the API requests are sent from your mobile device, you can insert some device information in User-Agent header, and then check it in your api controllers, for example:

```
class MyApisController < ApplicationController
  def foo
    # ...
    if request.user_agent != "your_device_id"
      head :unprocessable_entity
      return
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```